# jquery file upload and write results to db using blueImp script

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to upload files to my server via jquery, and once upload is complete write filename to a db somewhere.

I have the script working, in that it upload files to give dir,I got from here:
    [File Uploader](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

I don't even know where to begin to put the code for the db write.

I assume i would need to do an ajax call at somepoint of the function processing.  Is that the function on basic.html?

```
$(function () {
// Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
            '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'fileUploader/server/php/';
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
    });
 },

    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
},
}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
.parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');

});
```

or somewhere else?

Comment: `var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
            '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'fileUploader/server/php/';` is this set up properly? Because this look like it's could be the default url from plug-in

Comment: html has no "functions". html is not a programming language, it's a markup language.